# Is there a way to bypass HSTS protocol?

Tags: networking, security

Is there a way to **bypass the HTTP Strict Transfer Protocol** (HSTS) which has been used nowadays by many sites like Google services,banking Services, etc.?

I know that HSTS protocol forces a web client to use SECURE transmission (HTTPS) i.e the certificates, keys are sent in encrypted form. Is it possible to send them in **plain text format**? Will the web server accept it as **Plain-text**

I came across a blog which says its possible by implementing MITM (Man In The Middle) attack in the network. Is it true?

Comment: What are you even asking about? Whether HSTS has security vulnerabilities? Or perhaps if you can force sites to use HTTP instead of HTTPS (you can’t)? Or how to clear the HSTS cache in your browser?

Comment: i want to access HTTPS sites using HTTP proxy? is there a way to do it.

Comment: Well of course. A `CONNECT` tunnel. This is the normal way of accessing HTTPS via proxy. After all, there are no HTTPS proxies.

Comment: Do you have a particular browser that you are asking about, or are you willing to use any browser?  Are you using Windows?

Comment: **Please don't make substantial changes to what you are asking in a question that already has answers.** Your [revision 2](http://superuser.com/revisions/912728/2) essentially *asks a different question* compared to the original, completely invalidating the existing answer (which you seemingly accepted just before submitting the edit). It is often better to post a completely new question (as a separate question post) than make substantial, answer-invalidating changes to an existing one once the existing question has been answered, even if the existing one was put on hold or closed.

Comment: @Kevin : yes, im using windows & willing to use any browser!

Comment: @Daniel : CONNECT method is blocked by my isp.only GET is allowed

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Sorry sir, im new to this community, Hereafter i will correct my mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: I rolled back the question to the initial state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of HTTP Strict Transport Security, which is described in detail in [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797), is to ensure that requests are sent securely as determined by the respective site's policy. It is not a security protocol in and of itself; it simply instructs the web browser to force the use of secure transport (HTTPS) rather than insecure transport (HTTP) for a particular host and for a predetermined period of time.

There are a few possibilities for disabling HSTS for a host, but they all require access to the plaintext data of the encrypted HTTPS stream. This basically means that if you are in a position of disabling HSTS for a host, then you are already in a position of being able to manipulate communications with that host, and so you don't need to disable HSTS for that host.

The most obvious possibility would be that which is spelled out in the RFC's [section 6.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-6.1.1), setting the max-age directive to 0. That will cause a compliant client (web browser) to remove the host name from its list of known HSTS hosts.

An alternative might be to directly manipulate [the browser's HSTS store](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-5.3). That can be made more difficult by the browser vendor by using various cryptographic techniques (the code for which has already been written, since it is needed for HTTPS anyway) or by privilege separation.

However, even if you do this, the HSTS header and/or a permanent redirect to use HTTPS is likely to be retransmitted on the next request to the same host, which [will cause the secure status of the host to be reestablished by the client](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-5.3) for the duration specified by the server.

The RFC's [section 12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-12) gives implementation advice for clients. Particularly, [section 12.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-12.1) says there should be no user recourse in case of security-related errors.

However, of course, since HSTS is simply a mechanism to tell the client to use HTTPS rather than HTTP for a given host name, **all relevant attacks against HTTPS remain.** This means, for example, that if you can control the client's root certificate store or if you are able to obtain a certificate for the host for which you control the private key, you have the ability to successfully MITM such a session. *This is not affected by the presence or absence of HSTS on the specific host name.*

Many attacks against HTTPS can be made considerably more difficult by implementing proper [DNSSEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions) in combination with the client doing proper [DANE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-based_Authentication_of_Named_Entities) ([RFC 6698](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6698), [RFC 7218](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7218)) validation. For example, the combination of HSTS, proper validation of DNSSEC and proper validation of DANE would likely have made [Lenovo's Superfish](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/82035/2138) SSL-intercepting proxy impossible.